# How to get row & cell in object

Tags: c#, winforms, object, combobox

I have object from `combobox.DataSource` and I need to use `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` inside the object or data source if I can. I want also to loop through this data and I don't know how because can't get cells from it.

Is there any way to use data in data source or object?

[image: This is object I want to use cells inside it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `object` just cast it back.

Supposedly, you are the one who assigned a value to `CmbUnitName.DataSource` and you should know the type of this object. In this case you can easily cast it back to collection/datatable and loop through it.

For example, if it holds a list of objects of class `Unit`:

```
//cast it back
var cmbUnits = (List<Unit>) CmbUnitName.DataSource;
//loop through collection
foreach(var unit in cmbUnits) 
{
    //access fields/properties
    Console.WriteLine(unit.Id+" "+unit.UnitName);
}
```

The part after casting (looping through elements and properties) will heavily depend on the nature of your data source. In any case, as soon as you know the type, you should be able to figure out how to traverse it.

If you don't know the type of original object and, for some reason, can't find it from the code, then you can determine it by calling [`CmbUnitName.DataSource.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.8).

Note that [`ComboBox.DataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.datasource?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't hold an arbitrary object. The property value must be:

> An object that implements the IList interface or an Array.

So, most of the times you should be able to cast it back to [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netframework-4.8). You can try this, if you want to create some kind of generic implementation that will work for *any* data-bound combobox. But I have a strong feeling that in your case you just need to cast `DataSource` to original type.

Answer (score 0):

If you have object data, you can use:

```
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            TestObject current = (TestObject)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
            MessageBox.Show(current.Value.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: i can't use SelectedValue  because combo box coming from anther form 
i want to take data inside it and loop & get cells from it